# How browser find out file name in downloads?

Tags: browser, download, filenames

You may say it will look at `Content-Disposition` for file name, but I'm talking about where there's nothing in that header and also URL is not so straight forward like `http://website.com/myfile.zip`. I leave some examples here but wondering how browser (I use FireFox) find out the right name in `save as dialog`. Does it know the URL syntax for famous websites ?

```
download links in sourceforge.net
download links in cnet.com
download from your own localhost
```

I used `Fiddler2` for reverse engineering.

URL: http://mesh.dl.sourceforge.net/project/npp-plugins/Function List/FunctionList Plugin v2.1/FunctionList_2_1_UNI_dll.zip

Fiddler output sample:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 13 Nov 2010 22:46:31 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.9 (Debian)
Last-Modified: Thu, 18 Feb 2010 04:35:26 GMT
ETag: "142a602c-1fe24-47fd87eed7f80"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 130596
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/zip
```

EDIT: Problem is `Content-Disposition` is not set at final response, instead it at one of redirection. `HttpWebRespose` header contains last `response header` (`AllowAutoRedirec`t = `true`). I need to keep track of all responses and check if there is a `Content-Disposition` then remember it. How ?

Comment: No, browsers developers don't use to make special code for "famous" websites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *do* use `content-disposition` or any other standard method. See this example I just get from SourceForge using [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829/):

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.9
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="FunctionList_2_1_UNI_dll.zip"
Location: http://mesh.dl.sourceforge.net/project/npp-plugins/Function%20List/FunctionList%20Plugin%20v2.1/FunctionList_2_1_UNI_dll.zip
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sat, 13 Nov 2010 22:30:00 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.26
```

Note that they also use a redirect, maybe you get confused by that.

Answer (score 0):

If its not the filename attribute of the Content-Disposition header, its likely some HTTP 302 redirect, or a hidden `iframe` with the file download.